# Wake suspended computer on IP traffic

Tags: networking, sleep, wake-on-lan

I have a server I seldom use. I would like to set it up to automatically suspend on idle or absence of network traffic.

1) When new traffic arrives, is it possible to wake the computer on any IP packet received (not WOL packets, but IP packets) so that the server responds to requests but stays sleeping most of the time?

2) Do Ethernet chipsets usually support responding to ARP traffic without waking the computer? This would be needed to receive IP traffic.

Comment: An answer to this question is dependent on the equipment you are using. Please add the make/models of the nics, router, switches if any.

Comment: I still do not own the hardware, or I'm willing to switch to any suitable one. If you know some hardware that is suitable, let me know! Thank you!